# MySQL - select column dynamically

Tags: mysql, dynamic

I have a table with accounts and 12 monthly balances like below

```
Account | Fiscal Start | Month 1 | Month 2 | ... | Month 12
--------------------------------------------
12345          6         100.00     145.00   ...    199.00
56789          6         200.00     245.00   ...    299.00
```

The Fiscal Start indicates that column "Month 6" is January

I'd like to write a query that can do something like

```
SELECT Account,CONCAT('Month ','6') as 'January',CONCAT('Month ','7') as 'February'...
```

OR using a Function to make the correct selection

```
SELECT Account,COLUMNFUNC('6') as January,COLUMNFUNC('7') as February...
```

I've tried both the query and the function.
With the function I am only able to return `Month X` as text as it is invalid to perform a dynamic MySQL statement in a function  eg SELECT CONCAT('Month ',monthNumber)

I'd like to avoid writing a massive CASE statement for each column  ( Especially when this will apply to a weekly table )

Limitations
- I can't change the layout of the table
- I can't use a procedure since the reporting system only allows for a single query (so I can't do a nice prepare and exec)

Comment: Your data structure is causing most of the problems here because it violated the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule). Switching to a properly [database normal structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) would avoid this. If you can't change the layout of the table, that's really unfortunate. Are you sure you can't create a derivative table in a more orderly format, even a temporary table?

Comment: Why don't you use PL/SQL? Dynamic Querying can be easily handled with that

Comment: @tadman  Unfortunately I'm stuck with the layout.  Creating a derivative table is going to be my next step.  Was looking for a way to do it in a query.